# Google Cloud Endpoints with custom path and API name

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

In Google Cloud Endpoints, the path to a resource is given by:

1. The path configured in the web.xml for the EndpointsServlet (e.g., api)
2. The name given in the @API annoation, under the "name" property (e.g., myapi)
3. The version (e.g., v1)
4. The name given to the method, under the "path" property. (e.g., asset)

In the example above, the actual path will be /api/myapi/v1/asset

Now, the problem is that I don't want the "myapi" layer. There are two ways I can do this:

1. I can map /* to the EndpointsServlet, and change myapi to api. However, I don't really want to do this, because there are other paths (e.g., static files) in the application that I am not using for the API, and most annoying of all is that the 404 pages stops working.
2. I tried using an empty string for the @API name, but the framework doesn't allow that (automatically sets it to myapi)

Is there a way to do #2 and stop the framework from prefixing the path with the "api" part (and keep the version)?

Comment: I think if all of your `@ApiMethod` paths begin with `/` then it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/annotations#attributes), you need to specify a name in the @API annotation, otherwise myapi will be used as you stated.

You can delete the `/_ah/api` part of the path from the endpoint by setting the url-pattern in the web.xml to `/*`. Then in the openapi.json you set the basePath to `/`. The final path will start from the API annotation. In this case `/myapi/v1/asset`. You can set myapi to whatever value you want.

I know this is your #1, but it's the closest way I found.